# PostgreSQL Group by ignore nulls unless null is only value

Tags: postgresql, group-by, null

I have data that looks like this:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | x |
| value1 | x |
| value1 | (null) |
| value2 | y |
| value2 | y |
| value3 | (null) |
| value3 | (null) |

I want to **Count Distinct values in Column1 and Group by Column 2 where it ignore nulls unless null is the only value**. expected result would be:

| Column2 | Count Distinct Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| y | 1 |
| (null) | 1 |

any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: For each row, either column2 is NULL, or it is not.  If it is NULL, then the only value for that column in that row is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to Count Distinct values in Column1 and Group by Column 2 where it ignore nulls unless null is the only value

I assume you mean to "ignore rows where `column2` is null, unless the `column1` value does not appear in other rows" - like the "*value3*" that appears *only* in rows where `column2` is null?

You can do such filtering like this:

```
SELECT
    count(DISTINCT column1) FILTER (
        WHERE column2 IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM example i WHERE i.column1 = o.column1 AND i.column2 IS NOT NULL
        )
    ),
    column2
FROM example o
GROUP BY column2;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a2ddf7b6bd7fe51d79a004ff59b34a21))</sup>

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. I figured out my own solution but I will try yours as well to see if it does what I wanted it to. thanks!

Comment: @serghc Ah, using `NOT IN` makes this [a bit more concise](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b5ea88e757b515cc4480b74a0889ebc3). Btw you don't need the `UNION`, you can [just `OR` the conditions](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=48124b3a57c3d5546694fef4238bffb2)

Answer (score 0):

OP here.

I was able to answer my question. I ended up using a union between 2 queries to get what I was looking for. the first query counts the non-null groups and the second counts the null group but with a CTE to exclude values already counted in the first query.

code I used below:

```
select count (distinct column1), column2 
from table
where column2 is not null
group by column2

union 

select count (distinct column1), column2
from table
where column1 not in (
    select distinct column1 from table
           where column2 is not null)
and column2 is null
group by column2
```

Thanks for the input!

Comment: There is no CTE involved, you are using a sub query.